# How to show $GL(n, \mathbb R)/GL(n-k, \mathbb R)\cong S_k(V)$..

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb R$. Can anyone help me showing the groups $GL(n, \mathbb R)/GL(n-k, \mathbb R)$ and $$S_k(V)=\{A:\mathbb R^k\rightarrow V: A\ \textrm{is linear and}\ \textrm{ker}(A)=\{0\}\},$$ are isomorphic? Any help will be valuable, thanks..

Answer (score 1):

The statement as written is not correct.  E.g. take $n = 2$ and $k  = 1$.
Then $GL(2,\mathbb R)/GL(1,\mathbb )$ is $ 4 -1 = 3$ dimensional (it is $PGL(2,\mathbb R)$), while $S_1(V)$ is the space of two by one matrices of rank one (equivalently, the space of all non-zero two by one matrices), which is $2$-dimensional.

What is the source of the statement? Are you sure that you've interpreted the statement correctly?

Comment: I've changed the set $S_k(V)$...

Comment: @PtF: unfortunately the edit doesn't seem to deal with Matt E's objection; you've just described the same object in a different way.

Comment: @Asal what if I change $GL(n, \mathbb R)$ by $O(n)$?